# How can I measure the distance between each pair of carbon alphas in overlayed protein structures?

Tags: python, protein-structure, pymol

I am trying to make a figure in which the protein structures are colored by the distance between the calphas in the overlayed structures.

I am comparing our cryoEM structure to that of a previous crystal structure and trying to show the major distance shifts in an easy to look at manner. I can get the RMSD using some online servers but it doesn't give me a good visual way of looking at the data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not an expert here, but you could try to create a pdb with only c-alpha where B factor column has value according to bond lenght (proportional to it) and then color by b factor spectrum, I am sure there is some command about this : https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Spectrum

Answer (score 1):

Ok, quite late.... my code stolen from https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Spectrum as per in my comment:

> Not an expert here, but you could try to create a pdb with only c-alpha where B factor column has value according to bond lenght (proportional to it) and then color by b factor spectrum, I am sure there is some command about this : pymolwiki.org/index.php/Spectrum –

code using a fake peptide created with `cmd.fab('AFGVAL', 'peptide_1')` :

`peptide_1.pdb` :

```
ATOM      1  N   ALA     1      19.613   5.728  -6.281  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  CA  ALA     1      20.289   7.022  -6.281  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      3  C   ALA     1      21.789   6.848  -6.281  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      4  O   ALA     1      22.320   5.731  -6.292  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM      5  CB  ALA     1      19.781   7.814  -5.064  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  H   ALA     1      20.159   4.796  -6.281  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      7  HA  ALA     1      20.021   7.561  -7.209  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      8 1HB  ALA     1      18.685   7.964  -5.100  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9 2HB  ALA     1      20.005   7.300  -4.109  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10 3HB  ALA     1      20.237   8.819  -5.007  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     11  N   PHE     2      22.540   7.897  -6.270  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     12  CA  PHE     2      23.990   7.730  -6.270  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     13  C   PHE     2      24.690   9.068  -6.255  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     14  O   PHE     2      24.050  10.156  -6.244  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     15  CB  PHE     2      24.437   6.942  -7.538  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     16  CG  PHE     2      23.824   5.546  -7.729  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     17  CD1 PHE     2      22.610   5.411  -8.413  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     18  CD2 PHE     2      24.430   4.416  -7.174  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     19  CE1 PHE     2      22.002   4.165  -8.523  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     20  CE2 PHE     2      23.826   3.167  -7.294  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     21  CZ  PHE     2      22.611   3.043  -7.966  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     22  H   PHE     2      22.130   8.821  -6.260  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     23  HA  PHE     2      24.287   7.177  -5.358  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     24 2HB  PHE     2      25.541   6.842  -7.539  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     25 3HB  PHE     2      24.233   7.549  -8.444  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     26 1HD  PHE     2      22.116   6.283  -8.820  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     27 2HD  PHE     2      25.362   4.509  -6.633  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     28 1HE  PHE     2      21.050   4.077  -9.026  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     29 2HE  PHE     2      24.295   2.298  -6.857  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     30  HZ  PHE     2      22.134   2.079  -8.049  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     31  N   GLY     3      25.980   9.099  -6.253  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     32  CA  GLY     3      26.656  10.393  -6.239  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     33  C   GLY     3      28.155  10.220  -6.239  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     34  O   GLY     3      28.685   9.105  -6.251  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     35  H   GLY     3      26.513   8.242  -6.261  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     36 3HA  GLY     3      26.365  10.908  -5.371  0.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     37  HA  GLY     3      26.378  10.953  -7.151  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     38  N   VAL     4      28.906  11.269  -6.227  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     39  CA  VAL     4      30.356  11.101  -6.228  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     40  C   VAL     4      31.055  12.440  -6.212  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     41  O   VAL     4      30.429  13.507  -6.201  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     42  CB  VAL     4      30.798  10.251  -7.484  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     43  CG1 VAL     4      32.326  10.136  -7.737  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     44  CG2 VAL     4      30.276   8.794  -7.470  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     45  H   VAL     4      28.497  12.192  -6.217  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     46  HA  VAL     4      30.654  10.571  -5.305  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     47  HB  VAL     4      30.366  10.744  -8.381  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     48 1HG1 VAL     4      32.862   9.673  -6.888  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     49 2HG1 VAL     4      32.559   9.537  -8.638  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     50 3HG1 VAL     4      32.799  11.120  -7.921  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     51 1HG2 VAL     4      29.177   8.752  -7.361  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     52 2HG2 VAL     4      30.510   8.264  -8.413  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     53 3HG2 VAL     4      30.710   8.201  -6.643  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     54  N   ALA     5      32.345  12.471  -6.211  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     55  CA  ALA     5      33.021  13.765  -6.196  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     56  C   ALA     5      34.521  13.592  -6.197  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     57  O   ALA     5      35.052  12.475  -6.219  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     58  CB  ALA     5      32.511  14.544  -4.971  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     59  H   ALA     5      32.879  11.614  -6.220  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     60  HA  ALA     5      32.753  14.314  -7.119  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     61 1HB  ALA     5      31.415  14.694  -5.007  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     62 2HB  ALA     5      32.734  14.020  -4.022  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     63 3HB  ALA     5      32.967  15.549  -4.903  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     64  N   LEU     6      35.271  14.641  -6.173  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     65  CA  LEU     6      36.722  14.473  -6.173  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     66  C   LEU     6      37.420  15.811  -6.143  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     67  O   LEU     6      36.792  16.881  -6.122  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     68  CB  LEU     6      37.174  13.638  -7.404  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     69  CG  LEU     6      36.580  12.214  -7.580  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     70  CD1 LEU     6      37.231  11.514  -8.782  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     71  CD2 LEU     6      36.743  11.343  -6.323  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     72  H   LEU     6      34.862  15.564  -6.154  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     73  HA  LEU     6      37.013  13.950  -5.245  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     74 2HB  LEU     6      38.279  13.552  -7.384  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     75 3HB  LEU     6      36.958  14.216  -8.325  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     76  HG  LEU     6      35.495  12.316  -7.792  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     77 1HD1 LEU     6      37.097  12.092  -9.716  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     78 2HD1 LEU     6      38.318  11.367  -8.642  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     79 3HD1 LEU     6      36.787  10.518  -8.962  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     80 1HD2 LEU     6      37.799  11.259  -6.005  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     81 2HD2 LEU     6      36.175  11.759  -5.470  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     82 3HD2 LEU     6      36.357  10.318  -6.476  1.00  0.00           H  
TER   
END
```

`peptide_2_moved.pdb` , same pdb with some just carbon alpha moved by hand :

```
ATOM      1  N   ALA     1      19.613   5.728  -6.281  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  CA  ALA     1      20.289   7.022  -6.281  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      3  C   ALA     1      21.789   6.848  -6.281  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      4  O   ALA     1      22.320   5.731  -6.292  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM      5  CB  ALA     1      19.781   7.814  -5.064  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  H   ALA     1      20.159   4.796  -6.281  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      7  HA  ALA     1      20.021   7.561  -7.209  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      8 1HB  ALA     1      18.685   7.964  -5.100  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9 2HB  ALA     1      20.005   7.300  -4.109  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10 3HB  ALA     1      20.237   8.819  -5.007  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     11  N   PHE     2      22.540   7.897  -6.270  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     12  CA  PHE     2      24.369   7.337  -6.515  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     13  C   PHE     2      24.690   9.068  -6.255  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     14  O   PHE     2      24.050  10.156  -6.244  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     15  CB  PHE     2      24.437   6.942  -7.538  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     16  CG  PHE     2      23.824   5.546  -7.729  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     17  CD1 PHE     2      22.610   5.411  -8.413  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     18  CD2 PHE     2      24.430   4.416  -7.174  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     19  CE1 PHE     2      22.002   4.165  -8.523  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     20  CE2 PHE     2      23.826   3.167  -7.294  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     21  CZ  PHE     2      22.611   3.043  -7.966  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     22  H   PHE     2      22.130   8.821  -6.260  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     23  HA  PHE     2      24.287   7.177  -5.358  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     24 2HB  PHE     2      25.541   6.842  -7.539  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     25 3HB  PHE     2      24.233   7.549  -8.444  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     26 1HD  PHE     2      22.116   6.283  -8.820  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     27 2HD  PHE     2      25.362   4.509  -6.633  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     28 1HE  PHE     2      21.050   4.077  -9.026  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     29 2HE  PHE     2      24.295   2.298  -6.857  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     30  HZ  PHE     2      22.134   2.079  -8.049  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     31  N   GLY     3      25.980   9.099  -6.253  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     32  CA  GLY     3      26.656  10.393  -6.239  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     33  C   GLY     3      28.155  10.220  -6.239  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     34  O   GLY     3      28.685   9.105  -6.251  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     35  H   GLY     3      26.513   8.242  -6.261  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     36 3HA  GLY     3      26.365  10.908  -5.371  0.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     37  HA  GLY     3      26.378  10.953  -7.151  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     38  N   VAL     4      28.906  11.269  -6.227  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     39  CA  VAL     4      30.719  10.841  -6.509  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     40  C   VAL     4      31.055  12.440  -6.212  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     41  O   VAL     4      30.429  13.507  -6.201  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     42  CB  VAL     4      30.798  10.251  -7.484  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     43  CG1 VAL     4      32.326  10.136  -7.737  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     44  CG2 VAL     4      30.276   8.794  -7.470  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     45  H   VAL     4      28.497  12.192  -6.217  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     46  HA  VAL     4      30.654  10.571  -5.305  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     47  HB  VAL     4      30.366  10.744  -8.381  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     48 1HG1 VAL     4      32.862   9.673  -6.888  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     49 2HG1 VAL     4      32.559   9.537  -8.638  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     50 3HG1 VAL     4      32.799  11.120  -7.921  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     51 1HG2 VAL     4      29.177   8.752  -7.361  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     52 2HG2 VAL     4      30.510   8.264  -8.413  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     53 3HG2 VAL     4      30.710   8.201  -6.643  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     54  N   ALA     5      32.345  12.471  -6.211  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     55  CA  ALA     5      32.965  13.942  -6.049  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     56  C   ALA     5      34.521  13.592  -6.197  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     57  O   ALA     5      35.052  12.475  -6.219  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     58  CB  ALA     5      32.511  14.544  -4.971  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     59  H   ALA     5      32.879  11.614  -6.220  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     60  HA  ALA     5      32.753  14.314  -7.119  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     61 1HB  ALA     5      31.415  14.694  -5.007  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     62 2HB  ALA     5      32.734  14.020  -4.022  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     63 3HB  ALA     5      32.967  15.549  -4.903  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     64  N   LEU     6      35.271  14.641  -6.173  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM     65  CA  LEU     6      37.139  14.337  -6.385  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     66  C   LEU     6      37.420  15.811  -6.143  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     67  O   LEU     6      36.792  16.881  -6.122  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     68  CB  LEU     6      37.174  13.638  -7.404  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     69  CG  LEU     6      36.580  12.214  -7.580  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     70  CD1 LEU     6      37.231  11.514  -8.782  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     71  CD2 LEU     6      36.743  11.343  -6.323  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     72  H   LEU     6      34.862  15.564  -6.154  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     73  HA  LEU     6      37.013  13.950  -5.245  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     74 2HB  LEU     6      38.279  13.552  -7.384  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     75 3HB  LEU     6      36.958  14.216  -8.325  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     76  HG  LEU     6      35.495  12.316  -7.792  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     77 1HD1 LEU     6      37.097  12.092  -9.716  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     78 2HD1 LEU     6      38.318  11.367  -8.642  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     79 3HD1 LEU     6      36.787  10.518  -8.962  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     80 1HD2 LEU     6      37.799  11.259  -6.005  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     81 2HD2 LEU     6      36.175  11.759  -5.470  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     82 3HD2 LEU     6      36.357  10.318  -6.476  1.00  0.00           H  
TER   
END
```

code :

```
import pymol

import math

from pymol import (
                    
                    cmd ,
                    stored 
                    )

print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')

pymol.finish_launching()


cmd.set('internal_gui_width' ,  '500')

cmd.load('peptide_1.pdb' , 'peptide_1')

cmd.load('peptide_2_moved.pdb' , 'peptide_2_moved')

diff_len = lambda x,y : math.sqrt((x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0]) + (x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1]) + (x[2]-y[2])*(x[2]-y[2]))



cmd.select('peptide_1_CA' ,'peptide_1 and name CA')

cmd.select('peptide_2_moved_CA' ,'peptide_2_moved and name CA')

stored.peptide_1_CA_coord = []

stored.peptide_2_moved_CA_coord = []

cmd.iterate_state('1' , 'peptide_1_CA' , 'stored.peptide_1_CA_coord.append((x,y,z))')
            
cmd.iterate_state('1' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA' , 'stored.peptide_2_moved_CA_coord.append((x,y,z))')


print('stored.peptide_1_CA_coord : ' , stored.peptide_1_CA_coord)

print('stored.peptide_2_moved_CA_coord : ' , stored.peptide_2_moved_CA_coord)

stored.newB = list(map(lambda x,y: diff_len(x,y), stored.peptide_2_moved_CA_coord, stored.peptide_1_CA_coord))

print('\nstorednewB to be passed : ', stored.newB , '\n')

cmd.alter('peptide_2_moved_CA', 'b=stored.newB.pop(0)')


cmd.save('peptide_2_moved_CA.pdb' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA')

cmd.spectrum('b', 'rainbow_rev' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA' , '0' , '1')


cmd.color('lightblue' , 'peptide_1' )

cmd.set('cartoon_transparency' , '0.5', 'peptide_1')

cmd.alphatoall('peptide_2_moved')


cmd.save('peptide_2_moved_CA_alphatoall.pdb' , 'peptide_2_moved')


cmd.load('peptide_2_moved_CA_alphatoall.pdb' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA_alphatoall')

cmd.spectrum('b', 'rainbow_rev' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA_alphatoall' , '0' , '1')
```

output:

```
########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################
          ('2.3.0'
...
stored.peptide_1_CA_coord :  [(20.288999557495117, 7.021999835968018, -6.281000137329102), (23.989999771118164, 7.730000019073486, -6.269999980926514), (26.6560001373291, 10.392999649047852, -6.238999843597412), (30.356000900268555, 11.10099983215332, -6.228000164031982), (33.020999908447266, 13.765000343322754, -6.196000099182129), (36.72200012207031, 14.472999572753906, -6.172999858856201)]
stored.peptide_2_moved_CA_coord :  [(20.288999557495117, 7.021999835968018, -6.281000137329102), (24.368999481201172, 7.336999893188477, -6.514999866485596), (26.6560001373291, 10.392999649047852, -6.238999843597412), (30.7189998626709, 10.840999603271484, -6.508999824523926), (32.96500015258789, 13.942000389099121, -6.048999786376953), (37.138999938964844, 14.336999893188477, -6.385000228881836)]

storednewB to be passed :  [0.0, 0.5984269572074781, 0.0, 0.5275691186189471, 0.23679966390593804, 0.48716415818795433]
```

showing in pymol window:

[image]

that is the CAs trace of moved (rainbow colored) vs original (lightblue [lightgray out of ray to png]) according to Palette https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Palette_Colorbars `rainbow_rev` :

[image]

that goes from red = 0 to BLUE = 1 as set out in

`cmd.spectrum('b', 'rainbow_rev' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA' , '0' , '1')`

againg transferred calculated CAs to all atom using `AlphaToAll` :

`cmd.alphatoall('peptide_2_moved')` (check it into code) [image]

To use `spectrum` from min to max of the actual distance differences use in code above:

```
.....

stored.min = min(stored.newB)

stored.max = max(stored.newB)

print('\nmin of storednewB : ' , stored.min)

print('\nmax of storednewB : ' , stored.max)

print('\n')


cmd.alter('peptide_2_moved_CA', 'b=stored.newB.pop(0)')

cmd.save('peptide_2_moved_CA.pdb' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA')


cmd.spectrum('b', 'rainbow_rev' , 'peptide_2_moved_CA' , stored.min , stored.max)
....
```

[image]